# Java Spring Internationalization (i18n) problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

Im trying to learn developing multilingual websites with Java Spring.
After watching a few tutorials i understood how it works.
But it seems that im making some mistakes.

Project structure:

```
src
   └───  main
       ├───  java
       │   └───  com
       │       └───  example_project
       │           └───  config
       │               └─── WebMvcConfig
       └───  resources
           ├───  i18n
           │   ├─── messages_en.properties
           │   └─── messages_fr.properties
           ├───  static
           └───  templates
```

---

WebMvcConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource msgSrc = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        msgSrc.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        msgSrc.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return msgSrc;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("lang_cookie");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry reg) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        reg.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

---

LandingController.java

```
@Controller
public class LandingController {

    @Layout("layout/default")
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() { return "index"; }

}
```

index.html

```
<div th:fragment="content">
    <ul>
        <li><a th:href="@{/?lang=en}"><img src="/assets/images/en.png"></a></li>
        <li><a th:href="@{/?lang=fr}"><img src="/assets/images/fr.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p th:text="#{hello}"></p>
</div>
```

Its loading only "en" properties file, when im clicking to "fr" link its reloading but not loading the "fr" properties file.

I cant understand where is the problem.

Comment: Where *what* problem is?

Comment: Its loading only en properties file, when im clicking to fr link its reloading but not loading the fr properties file.

Comment: How do you know, when there is no text on you page?

Comment: I forgot to add here, i will edit now

Answer (score 0):

Your MessageSource is not able to find the message with key "hello" in both properties files. If the message source is not able to find the message in fr properties, it will return the one from en.
Please make sure that you defined the message in both files

- messages_en.properties

hello=Hello in en

- messages_fr.properties

hello=Hello in fr

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i already have those two properties files with same key but when im clicking to url ?lang=fr the site is refreshing but it doesn't load fr properties file